# In my code the if part is working correctly however, the else part is not executing

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to set up OTP verification

I have already tried many possibilities with the if and else, however, it didn't help out.

```java
 public class userLogin extends Activity {

    EditText phnNum=null, veri = null;

    FirebaseAuth au;
    Button forgotpass, login;
    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks otp;

    String verifyCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.userlogin);

        login = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        phnNum = findViewById(R.id.enter_phone);
        forgotpass = findViewById(R.id.forgot_pass);

        au = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                    if ((phnNum.getText().toString()).equals("")) {

                    (Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the phone number and proceed to receive an OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
                    }


                     else{ 
                         otp = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                                verifyCode = s;
                                (Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The OTP Code has been send, please verify the code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();


                            }
                         };


                     }
                 }

        });
    }

            public void send_sms (View v){

                String i = (phnNum.getText()).toString();
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(i, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this, otp);

                login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override

                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent u = new Intent(view.getContext(), otp_verify.class);
                        startActivity(u);
                    }
                });

            }



            //SignIn Method
            // We will pass value in the method with "PhoneAuthCredential" data-type.
            public void SignIn(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

                //" au " is the firebase variable and call the method

                    au.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            (Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Sign-In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
                            }
                        else{
                            (Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

When I log-in with blank EditText, the if part executes but when I enter the phone number it doesn't execute the else part. I expect the when the user enters their phone number the else part should execute.

Comment: @Fantômas it might not be useful for your but for some it may not. I am not as good as you. If I were I would not have asked. And it doesn't mean that you will mark it as not useful

Comment: How do you check the `else` part is never invoked?

Comment: Just below the if there is the else part, I check by giving the condition just the opposite, still, it didn't execute. My intention was that onClick if there the EditText is empty then I will ask the user to enter the data, however, if the user entered the Data then to execute onClick. You can see I have used if and else after onClick function. @S-Sh

Comment: I mean, do you add breakpoints/logs/other notifications to be sure the code is not actually executed? It seems you **instantiate** your `otp` callback variable but you **do not use** it (at least, in `onClick` handler). Besides, note the `otp` is just callback and not actual code of verification.

Comment: Hey, thank for that I didn't add the Log.e to check. Let me check and see whether it execute or not. I just forgot about that. @S-Sh

Comment: Due to the limit of adding code in Stack flow, I didn't add the whole code just the if and else part. Once the else part executed, I set a method which will run Immediately when onClick on the Login button and should execute another activity. However, when my App run the if part works fine not doubt, but i feel it 
 doesn't comes out of the if and else statement. Like it just stuck there. @S-Sh

Comment: Hey @S-Sh, I have uploaded the full code, can you please see and tell me which part I have coded wrong. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String i = (phnNum.getText()).toString();

if ("".equals(i)) {

    (Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the phone number and proceed to receive an OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
} else { 

    // 1. prepare callback for async call
     otp = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            verifyCode = s;
            (Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The OTP Code has been send, please verify the code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();

            Intent u = new Intent(userLogin.this, otp_verify.class);
            startActivity(u);
        }
     };


    // 2. execute actual call
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(i, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, userLogin.this, otp);

 }
```

The code snippet prepares callback and uses it on Firebase auth call. When the verification code is actually sent, the `onCodeSent` called and new activity launched.

Comment: I'm still not sure I undestand your intents correctly. Please, check the code above and clarify the problem if necessary. Hope it helps.